# button should show only for iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap lay out....
when i reduce the browser window you will see a menu by clicking a button....
but the button should show only for iphone lay out.....
but the button is showing for desktop how to fix it....

http://jsfiddle.net/r4SqC/4/embedded/result/

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>

.navbar .btn-navbar {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #040404;
display: block;
padding: 0;
}
.navbar-inverse .btn-navbar {
color: #ffffff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
background-color: #0e0e0e;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #040404);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#151515), to(#040404));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #040404);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #040404);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #151515, #040404);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border-color: #040404 #040404 #000000;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff151515', endColorstr='#ff040404', GradientType=0);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
```

Comment: Did you bother checking your browser's console? I get many errors

Comment: yeah but this with respect to css

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.visible-phone` class if you only want the element to display on phones. See "Responsive Utility Class" under: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: @user2136828 Sure thing: check out http://jsfiddle.net/r4SqC/5/. I added class="visible-phone" to the parent <li>.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a media query to target only screens of a certain size (which would exclude desktops, but include mobile browsers *like* that of the iPhone). The screen dimensions of an iPhone are 320px x 480 px in portrait, and 480x320 in landscape ([see here](http://upstageapp.com/resources)). So you'd have something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    selector { color: red }
}
```

The Mozilla Developer Network has [a good article going into more detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries).